# parsley validation on bootstrap wizard

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, parsley.js

I used bootstrap wizard to make multi step form
For validation, I used Parsley
the problem is ( when i click on next button to go to the second tap, the validation work , if validation return true, i go . if not, i have to correct the error then i go to the second tab,
but this process did not work for the other next clicks to move to third and other tabs , if i click next, i will move to the tab without validation check !

java script code

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {


            $('#rootwizard').bootstrapWizard({
              'onNext': function(tab, navigation, index) {
                var form = jQuery('#demo-form');
                    form.parsley().validate({group: 'tab'+index});

                    if (form.parsley().isValid({group: 'tab'+index})){

                window.alert(index);               
                  return true;
                } else {
                  return false;
                }
              },
              onPrevious: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                return true;
              },
              onTabShow: function(tab, navigation, index) {
                console.log("show : " + index);
              }
            });
});
```

And html code:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
                        <form id="demo-form" data-parsley-validate action="{{route('test')}}" method="post">
                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                            <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg " data-parsley-trigger="change" placeholder="col-form-label-lg" name="email" required="" data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-group="tab1">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg "  placeholder="col-form-label-lg" name="mailbox" required="" data-parsley-group="tab5">
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg "  placeholder="col-form-label-lg" name="projName" required="" data-parsley-group="tab2">
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
                            <button type="submit" id="sub-button" onclick="submitForms()">
                                submit
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Not too sure. Best call only `validate` and use that result, no need to also call `isValid`. If you have ajax/promise validations, you need to use whenValidate though.

Comment: Thank you for your help ..
The problem was in the <form> place ..the form should be outside the rootwizard div